# SQL : Update pivot table

Tags: sql

SQL Query :

```
SELECT id,mti,[24] AS nii,mid,tid,[63-D9] AS TxnType,[63-DB] AS batchStatus ,
 [39] AS respondCode,[61] AS batchNumber, uploadStatus
 FROM  (SELECT e.id,m.capDateTime,mti,procCode,mid,tid,uploadStatus,txnDate,txnTime,fieldNumber,fieldData FROM dbo.iso_fields e
 JOIN dbo.iso_main m ON e.id = m.id) a  PIVOT (MAX(fieldData)   FOR fieldNumber IN
([0],[1],[2],[3],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20], [21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],
[31],[32],[33],[34],[35],[36],[39],[40], [41],[42],[43],[44],[45],[46],[47],[48],[49],[50],[51],[52],[53],[54],[55],[56],[57],[58],[59],[60],
[61],[63],[64],[63-D9],[63-DB]))PIV
```

Im trying to Update the table for example :

```
UPDATE PIV SET batchStatus = 'C'
    SELECT id,mti,[24] AS nii,mid,tid,[63-D9] AS TxnType,[63-DB] AS batchStatus ,
     [39] AS respondCode,[61] AS batchNumber, uploadStatus
     FROM  (SELECT e.id,m.capDateTime,mti,procCode,mid,tid,uploadStatus,txnDate,txnTime,fieldNumber,fieldData FROM dbo.iso_fields e
     JOIN dbo.iso_main m ON e.id = m.id) a  PIVOT (MAX(fieldData)   FOR fieldNumber IN
    ([0],[1],[2],[3],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[12],[13],[14],[15],[16],[17],[18],[19],[20], [21],[22],[23],[24],[25],[26],[27],[28],[29],[30],
    [31],[32],[33],[34],[35],[36],[39],[40], [41],[42],[43],[44],[45],[46],[47],[48],[49],[50],[51],[52],[53],[54],[55],[56],[57],[58],[59],[60],
    [61],[63],[64],[63-D9],[63-DB]))PIV
WHERE nii = '0000'
```

Im pretty sure that is not the correct syntax and im so horrible in pivot table's

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? "SQL" is a query language, not the name of a specific DBMS product (plus: your sample queries are invalid standard SQL)

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your query it seems you are updating a PIVOT "PIV" which is not possible. Pivot is with aggregation clause only. You can't update it.

If I understand your problem correctly you want to refresh the PIVOT data and if this assumption is correct then you need to update the main tables which you are using in PIVOT Or use a temporary tables to reflect the updated data.